# How to convert $ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac {d\theta}{(1+\sin^2\theta)} $ to a contour integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to convert 
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac {d\theta}{(1+\sin^2\theta)}
$$
to a contour integral.
I know that I can use the substitution $z=\cos\theta + i\sin\theta = e^{i\theta}$ to get $\sin\theta = \frac {(z^2 -1)}{2zi}$, and  $d\theta = \frac{dz}{zi}$

What I cannot understand is how to choose the contour curve to do the integration.
Some help will be very useful.

Comment: Your contour is the unit circle $|z| = 1$.

Comment: @kobe isn't that for the range $0$ to $2\pi$ ?

Comment: The parametrization $z = e^{i\theta}$, $-\pi \le \theta \le \pi$, traces out the unit circle as well. The trace starts with $z = -1$. If the range of $\theta$ was $[0,2\pi]$ instead, the trace would start from $z = 1$.